# Add local jar to pom.xml of Spring boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar

I have created two spring boot applications - `foo` and `bar`. I then created a jar file for `bar` with the command `mvn clean package`, which resulted in the `bar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` file. Using `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=target/bar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DpomFile=pom.xml` as mentioned in [this post](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-ways-to-add-and-work-with-a-jar-file-in-you), I installed this jar to my local .m2 repository.

Then in the pom.xml of `foo`, I added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foobarcompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, when I run the `foo` app from STS, it runs correctly, but if I try to run it form terminal with `mvn spring-boot:run` or try to package `foo` with `mvn clean package`, I get the following error:

```
package com.foobarcompany.bar.service does not exist
```

which is referring to a service present in the `bar` app that I'm calling from the `foo` app.

As far as I understand, the dependency is not correctly added and the reason it works from STS is because both applications are under the same workspace.

I have even tried adding a local maven repository as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project/36602256#36602256) but even that doesn't seem to work. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Could anyone please tell me what the correct way to add a local jar to another application is?

Comment: You should run mvn install to publish this JAR to your local .m2.  Use mvn deploy task to publish it to a remote repository that you have write access to.

Comment: You can't use a spring boot application as a dependency. If you need to share code make a separate module name it like `commons-code` or similar and use that as a dependency.

Comment: @duffymo I have run mvn install from bar, and it is available in my local .m2. But when I add this dependency in foo and then run mvn install, it cannot find the service defined in bar

Comment: @khmarbaise Can I convert an existing spring Spring boot application with packaging war into a multi-module application? Also, if there is a separate project baz that needs to use the services defined in bar, is it possible to use this module?

Comment: Yes of course you can...

Answer (score 1):

You missed artifactid, version and groupid, please use below command.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id>
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Reference:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: mvn clean install will install the jar to local .m2 folder

Comment: Do we have to define the artifactId, version and groupId if we use the command with the pom file?

Answer (score 0):

I have done mvn clean install to publish it to .m2 folder. After that I have added it as dependency (which you have already done). Last step is to add @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foobarcompany.bar", "com.foobarcompany.foo" }) on your main class, where your @SpringBootApplication is placed. I can start application with mvn spring-boot:run. This worked for me.

Comment: I had previously added @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foobarcompany") in the main class which should have picked both foo and bar. I tried with your method as well but it still doesn't work.